# windows showing black screen with cursor after installing Ubuntu

Tags: multi-boot, grub2, mbr

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with windows 10 and during installation I selected windows partition as device for boot loader installation. After restating i got:

```
There is no option to boot for windows 10 in the grub menu.
```

After reinstalling grub with boot-repair I was able to see the windows 10 option, but when I select windows it shows a black screen for 4-5 sec and returns to GRUB. Ubuntu is working fine.
I also tried to fix mbr and boot of windows by command at commend promote

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr  
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /scanos  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

After this and restart it showing only black screen with a courser.

I also tried reinstalling windows in same partition but it still showing black screen.
What should I do now?
I want only windows for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a seperate partition for the bootloader from windows. It sounds like you erased windows and then erased your boot loader with the reinstallation of windows. The boot loader doesn't require as much space that an operating system partition requires. Create a new partition for the bootloader.

To get windows 10 working go through the computers boot manager instead of GRUB. Do this by repeatedly tapping either the *ESC* key, or one of the function keys (usually f2, f8, f9, or f12, but it may be one of any of the others). Once in the computers boot menu (not GRUB), click on the boot options and select the device and partition you wish to boot from. This may not work if you overwrote your windows boot record, but you said you reinstalled windows on that partition so I think it will. Now if you erased the ubuntu boot loader, just start up the installation of Ubuntu again. From the Ubunto installation, make a smaller partition from the partition that you wish to install Ubuntu on. Have the smaller partition be about 200 megabytes, that is for the bootloader. Do not put the bootloader on the partion with Windows.

Comment: I have boot-info record which created by boot-repair which showing there is no operating system installed in the partition of Windows after reinstall. What should i do now should i format both partition and reinstall them again. My ubuntu is working fine i want Windows for some work for now like gaming and other stuffs.